# How to set a new raster band to a QgsPalettedRasterRenderer object?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

Is there a way to set the current raster band to an existing **QgsPalettedRasterRenderer** object? Other renderer have specific methods for that (e.g. setRedBand, setGreenBand, setBlueBand, setGrayBand, etc.).

For QgsPalettedRasterRenderer I haven't found anything like that. I guess it is done in a different manner (?).

```
renderer = layer.renderer()
assert isinstance(renderer, QgsPalettedRasterRenderer)

# Getting the current raster band is working:
print(renderer.band())  

# But how to set a new raster band? A setBand method does not exist.
renderer.setBand(band) # not working
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but as I understand, `QgsPalettedRasterRenderer` is for single band rasters, therefore, no need to have a setBand function for it. However, you could easily apply a palette of colours to your raster even if is multi band, by:

**Assumming you have all your imports done**

`rlayer = iface.addRasterLayer('path/to/raster', 'RasterLayerName')`

Create your own list of paletted colours `pcolor`.

```
pcolor = []

pcolor.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(-1, QColor("#d2ca97"), '-1'))    
pcolor.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0, QColor("#f7f7f7"), '0'))    
pcolor.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(1, QColor("#a1d99b"), '1'))    
pcolor.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(10, QColor("#41ab5d"), '10'))    
pcolor.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(25, QColor("#006d2c"), '25'))    
pcolor.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(50, QColor("#00441b"), '50'))
```

Assign the colour list to the `renderer`, using `band=1`

```
renderer = QgsPalettedRasterRenderer(rlayer.dataProvider(), 1, qgis.core.QgsPalettedRasterRenderer.colorTableToClassData(pcolor))
```

Set the renderer to your layer

```
rlayer.setRenderer(renderer)
```

trigger the repaint

```
rlayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Then you have a raster with paletted colours. Very useful for categorical values in rasters.

Comment: You can use QgsPalettedRasterRenderer also for multiband band rasters, e.g. using the second band of a 3 band raster should be fine.